# Dual boot with primary Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7, lubuntu

I've installed Lubuntu on my computer, but I let to be Windows primary. How do I get to Lubuntu?

I have no offer list while booting Windows, Windows is booting automatically without chance to change it to Lubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried to press f12 before it boots windows?

Comment: i have both OS on harddisk drive

Comment: You can enter the BIOS and activate the "boot" option in the boot section. After that you might be able to choose the OS (maybe you have to press a button like F12 to display the choice screen). When you're able to get in Lubuntu edit the file /boot/grub/grub.cfg to load the OS of your choice.

Comment: I'm able to choose boot device, not OS from boot device. And I can't get to Linux. Mr.Pixel's answer is solving my problem. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your description, it seems like your harddisk's MBR (the first sector, used to boot up from that harddisk) points to the Windows bootloader. The Windows bootloader is incompatible with most operating systems other than Windows itself though. This commonly happens when you install Windows after Linux, or if you "repair" Windows.

What you want is a bootloader that is compatible with both Linux & Windows. For instance, GRUB, the bootloader used by default by Ubuntu.

Updating/Reinstalling GRUB, should therefore fix your issue.

This answer explains particularly well how to proceed: https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/29365

You will need a bootable USB or install CD.